# How do I get response codes from Authorize.net with Kohana's payment module?

Tags: php, e-commerce, kohana, authorize.net

After you call the process() method, I want to get Authorize.net response codes and text. Or is that not included in the library. All I can see are `set_field()` and `process()` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is part of the code from the process() method:

```
$heading = substr_count($response, '|');

for ($i=1; $i <= $heading; $i++)
{
  $delimiter_position = strpos($response, '|');

  if ($delimiter_position !== False)
  {
    $response_code = substr($response, 0, $delimiter_position);
    $response_code = rtrim($response_code, '|');

    if($response_code == '')
      throw new Kohana_Exception('payment.gateway_connection_error');

    switch ($i)
    {
     case 1:
       return (($response_code == '1') ? explode('|', $response) : False); // Approved
     default:
       return False;
    }
  }
}
```

When you use the process method, it should return the response code as an array.